# How to make first input in a forEach loop hidden?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a foreach loop like this:

```
<c:forEach var="valuesInRows" items="${sprav.valuesInRows}" varStatus="statusInRows">
  <c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="statusInRow">
    <c:out value="${sprav.columnName[statusInRow.index]} : " />
    <f:input path="valuesInRows[${statusInRows.index}][${statusInRow.index}]" />
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Now I want to make the first c:out and f:input hidden. How do I achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `varStatus="counter"` attribute and check counter==0 to do something different on the first iteration.